# Is it safe to use Navigation component in an Adapter?

Tags: android-adapter, androidx, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using a recycler view to display a feed, and each item is a button defined in the xml view. I'm just curious if its safe to use the navigation component and navigate when clicking an item in the recycler view, from the adapter. I currently have an onClickListener setup for the button inside of onBindViewHolder, where in the onClick I set the following:

```
TabsFragmentDirections.ActionNavHomeToNavGroupsFeed action =
                        TabsFragmentDirections.actionNavHomeToNavGroupsFeed(
                                myListData.getGroupName()
                        );
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
```

where the Directions class is generated from using safe-args to pass an argument to the destination (from here https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data).

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I would say this is safe. Your adapter lives as long as your fragment/activity so it doesn't seem like there would be any chance of a leak.

---

Having said that, it is generally considered better practice to implement that type of logic outside of the adapter for better separation of concerns!

Comment: thank you!! & Would separating that logic from the adapter be done best with a callback?

Comment: Yes exactly! So some sort of interface that represents an `onClickListItem` event.